# Deepin OS not detecting external monitor connected via HDMI

Tags: multi-monitor, deepin

I have an installation of Deepin OS 15 dual-booted with Windows 10. Everything for the most part works fine, but I cannot get it to connect to an external monitor. The monitor in question is a 2560x1080p LG Ultrawide. I have done some research and installed various drivers (Intel's micro-processor drivers, NVIDIA's bumblebee package, etc.) but to no avail. No matter what I do, my `xrandr` output never changes:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And the output of `sudo lshw -C display`:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc000000-dcffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:dd000000-dd07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:320 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

My laptop's specs:

```
              ............                
          .';;;;;.       .,;,.            OS: Deepin 15.4.1 unstable
       .,;;;;;;;.       ';;;;;;;.         Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.9.0-deepin9-amd64
     .;::::::::'     .,::;;,''''',.       Uptime: 28m
    ,'.::::::::    .;;'.          ';      Packages: 1534
   ;'  'cccccc,   ,' :: '..        .:     Shell: bash 4.4.11
  ,,    :ccccc.  ;: .c, '' :.       ,;    Resolution: 1920x1080
 .l.     cllll' ., .lc  :; .l'       l.   WM: Mutter(DeepinGala)
 .c       :lllc  ;cl:  .l' .ll.      :'   WM Theme: Adwaita
 .l        'looc. .   ,o:  'oo'      c,   GTK Theme: deepin [GTK2/3]
 .o.         .:ool::coc'  .ooo'      o.   Icon Theme: deepin
  ::            .....   .;dddo      ;c    CPU: Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.801GHz
   l:...            .';lddddo.     ,o     GPU: GeForce GTX 1060
    lxxxxxdoolllodxxxxxxxxxc      :l      RAM: 1875MiB / 15941MiB
     ,dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxl.     'o,      
       ,dkkkkkkkkkkkkko;.    .;o;        
         .;okkkkkdl;.    .,cl:.          
             .,:cccccccc:,.
```

If there is any other information I can provide please let me know. I'm seriously at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am also having similar issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AkashKumar I didn't. I tried everything I could think of or find online. I think I narrowed it down to an issue with my graphics card.

Comment: Ii was working and suddenly stopped!! now I don't know why it's not detecting the another screen, but I remember the last thing I did before restarting my machine was installing new packages that is not related to the graphic things and I did upgrade all apt packages and dist upgrade